# Using @Transactional annotation for hibernate application resulting in error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I am trying to integrate spring with hibernate this morning. I want to use spring transaction manager. But getting the below error.  The error has something to do with @Trasactional Annotation. If i remove the annotation,im able to get the bean from the spring container.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19 cannot be cast to com.hibernate.dao.EvntDAOImpl
at com.hibernate.action.HibernateAction.main(HibernateAction.java:17)
```

Im pasting below my source code.

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>hibernate-tutorials</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-tutorials</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
     <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring ORM support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Hibernate Configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.hibernate.model.Evnt</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernatey.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

**EvntDAOImpl.java**

```
package com.hibernate.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.hibernate.model.Evnt;

@Repository(value="evntDAO")
@Transactional
public class EvntDAOImpl implements EvntDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void storeEvnt(Evnt evnt) {

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(evnt);

}
```

}

HibernateAction.java

```
package com.hibernate.action;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.hibernate.dao.EvntDAO;
import com.hibernate.dao.EvntDAOImpl;
import com.hibernate.model.Evnt;

public class HibernateAction {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context  = new         ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    EvntDAOImpl evntDAO = (EvntDAOImpl) context.getBean("evntDAO");
    Evnt evnt = new Evnt();
    evnt.setTitle("first Event");
    evnt.setDate(new Date());
    evntDAO.storeEvnt(evnt);

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the place where you are injecting `EventDaoImpl`.

Just replace

`@Autowired EventDaoImpl eventDaoImpl`

with

`@Autowired EventDao eventDao`

wherever you need Spring to autowire the dao.

Or if you are getting the bean from the applicationContext use:

`EvntDAO evntDAO = (EvntDAO) context.getBean("evntDAO");`

The problem is caused by the fact that the use of `@Transactional` annotation on the dao's implementation code means that Spring will create a [JDK dynamic proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) for it, which cannot be cast to the implementation class. [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) is the complete documentation of Spring's AOP capabilities (where the creation of JDK dynamic proxies and CGLib class proxies is fully explained).

What that essentially means is that because of `@Transactional`, when you call `context.getBean("evntDAO")` you don't get back your `EventDaoImpl` (as one would expect), but you actually get back an object whose class is `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` which has been created by Spring. That proxy object implements `EventDao` (and therefor can be cast to it) but it's signature has nothing to do with `EventDaoImpl` (and hence the `ClassCastException` since it does not extend `EventDaoImpl`). When a method is called on the proxy various things happen before and/or after the call is actually delegated to `EventDaoImpl` (what happens before/and or after the actual call to `EventDaoImpl` is controlled by Spring though the implementation of `InvocationHandler`).

Comment: Great..It worked.. Can you please elaborate this one "use of @Transactional on the dao's implementation code means that Spring will create a JDK proxy for it".

Comment: @BhargavKumarR No problem! I will update my answer later with more info because I am on a mobile device at the moment